# Google Cloud Spanner for Development

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Is there a way to setup a Development env for Google Cloud Spanner?

Is this this "How to run Cloud Spanner in a Container" for dev?
Or is the only solution to run a cloud spanner for dev a single node?
I think this is really expensive for dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment the only way is to run a single node for development as there is no local emulator.

GCP does have a $300 trial credit for new users, which would enable you to run the single node system at 8 hours a day for over a month with 1GB of storage.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty similar question to [this other post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289920/local-development-with-cloud-spanner), which mentions using CockroachDB––open source, so free to use. Both work in a similar fashion, as noted over there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [gcloud beta emulators](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators)